# label axis with different distance from the plot

Tags: r

Is there any way to set different distances between the label axes and the plot? I know I can set the distance of label axes to the plot with the par(mgp=c()) command, but I need to set different distances for x and y labels.

Thanks

Comment: I think @Henk meant [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried `mtext` to create each label yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change the distance between the plot and the labels then you can use:

```
par(mar = c(w,x,y,z) + a)
```

Where altering the values of `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` and `a` will alter the spacing between your plot and your axes. A helpful tutorial can be found here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/setting-graph-margins-in-r-using-the-par-function-and-lots-of-cow-milk/